# Limit the overlay of jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

There is a screen in my site where I want to show sign-up dialog, locking, but showing, member-only content: [whatiftopions](http://whatifoptions.com/Engine/Screens).

Currently, the jQuery dialog locks up the whole screen -- a user can only use browser buttons to navigate away from the screen. How can I make it, so the background overlay of the jQuery dialog covers only the area below the main navigation menu?

Thank you

Comment: You could resize the overlaid element, but that would only solve part of the problem: modal dialogs also tamper with focus transfer in such a way that elements in the dialog can only give focus to one another. Overriding that might be trickier. Are you sure a simple modeless dialog cannot do the job?

Comment: why can't user close the dialog?

Comment: because I want them to sign up before they can get to member-only content. Once signed up, the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frederic, thanks for your suggestion to use the non-modal dialog. That's what I ended up doing -- switched to non-modal and put an overlay div over the specific content.